# Tkinter and displaying iterating list

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, iterator

I have the following code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import itertools

l1 = [1, 'One', [[1, '1', '2'], [2, '3', '4'], [3, '5', '6']]]
l2 = [2, 'Two', [[1, 'one', 'two'], [2, 'three', 'four'], [3, 'five', 'six']]] 

def session(evt,contents):

    def setup_cards():
        cards = [stack[2] for stack in contents]
        setup = [iter(stack) for stack in cards] 
        return cards, setup

    def end():
        window.destroy()

    def start():
        print setup
        print cards

        pair = next(setup[0])

        def flip():
            side2cont.set(pair[2])
            flipbutton.configure(command=start)

        for stack in setup:
            try:
                for card in cards:
                    try:
                        side1cont.set(pair[1])
                        flipbutton.configure(command=flip)
                    except StopIteration:
                        continue
            except StopIteration:
                pair = next(setup[1])

    window = Toplevel()
    window.grab_set()
    window.title("Session")

    card_frame = Frame(window)
    card_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, padx=2, pady=2)

    button_frame = Frame(window)
    button_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=(5,0), padx=2)

    side1_frame = LabelFrame(card_frame, text="Side 1")
    side1_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

    side1cont = StringVar()
    side2cont = StringVar()

    side1 = Label(side1_frame, textvariable=side1cont)
    side1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

    side2_frame = LabelFrame(card_frame, text="Side 2")
    side2_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)

    side2 = Label(side2_frame, textvariable=side2cont)
    side2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

    flipbutton = Button(button_frame, text="Flip", command=start)
    flipbutton.grid(row=0, column=2)

    finishbutton = Button(button_frame, text="End", command=end)
    finishbutton.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=E)

    cards = setup_cards()[0]
    setup = setup_cards()[1]

w = Tk()
wbutton = Button(text='toplevel')
wbutton.bind('<Button-1>', lambda evt, args=(l1, l2): session(evt, args))
wbutton.pack()

w.mainloop()
```

It is piece of my project, I remade it just to the basics so it's easy to understand. In my project, function `session` accepts files, these are now emulated as lists `l1` and `l2`.

The point where I am struggling is when I hit `StopIteration` exception. I would like my script to do the following:
1. When iteration reaches end, switch to another iterator (next item in `setup` list, in this case `l2` iterator).
2. If no other iterators are present in `setup`, reset the iterator ("start over from the beginning").

The code above is the best I was able to come up with, that's why I'm turning to you folks. Thank you (also I'm newbie so I'm still struggling with basics of Python/programming in general).

Answer (score 0):

`StopIteration` is caught by `for` and not propagated further.  You may want to use `for…else`.

But your methods of iteration are weird, why not just use regular `for` loops?